# Center columns with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I have the following table:

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Transfer Entropy Results}
  \label{tab1:entropy}
  \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CC}
 \toprule
Causal test & Results  \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[1]{*}{Bitcoin $\rightarrow$ IPImicro}} & 0.015 \\
          & (-0.023) \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[0]{*}{IPImicro $\rightarrow$ Bitcoin }} & 0.091** \\
          & (-0.027) \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[0]{*}{Bitcoin $\rightarrow$ IPImacro}} & 0.007 \\
          & (-0.028) \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[1]{*}{IPImacro $\rightarrow$ Bitcoin }} & 0.073** \\
          & (-0.025) \\

\bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  \footnotesize
  \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Note:} This table presents the Transfer Entropy estimation results. Standard deviation in parentheses; *** p < 0.01; ** p < 0.05; * p < 0.10.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

What I want is to allign the numbers at the decimal marker using siunitx.

However, what I get is this:

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Transfer Entropy Results}
  \label{tab1:entropy}
  \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{2}{S}}
 \toprule
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{Causal test} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Regime 1} \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[1]{*}{Bitcoin $\rightarrow$ IPImicro}} & 0.015 \\
          & {(}-4.710{)} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[0]{*}{IPImicro $\rightarrow$ Bitcoin }} & 0.091** \\
          & {(}-4.710{)} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[0]{*}{Bitcoin $\rightarrow$ IPImacro}} & 0.007 \\
          & {(}-4.710{)} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[1]{*}{IPImacro $\rightarrow$ Bitcoin }} & 0.073** \\
          & {(}-4.710{)} \\

\bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  \footnotesize
  \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Note:} This table presents the Transfer Entropy estimation results.  Standard deviation in parentheses; *** p < 0.01; ** p < 0.05; * p < 0.10.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

The first column is alligned to the left. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I would like to get the exact same result as in example 1, just alligned at the decimal marker. In second step: Is it even possible to have the arrows below each other?

Comment: Could you please post a *complete*, compilable code, not just a fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- cause of your problem seems to be use of `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`
- you define three columns, but use only two ...
- I would not use `tabular*` table environment, in my opinion, the result is not nice
- as solution to your problem I put the column headers into `p` columns with width equal to half the text width
- in my MWE, I remove all unnecessary code, repair definition for `S` column type and use the [threeparttablex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttablex) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Transfer Entropy Results}
  \label{tab1:entropy}
  \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c 
                             S[input-open-uncertainty,
                               input-close-uncertainty,
                               table-space-text-pre=(,
                               table-space-text-post={**},
                               table-align-text-post=false,
                               table-format=-1.3]
                             }
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}p{0.5\linewidth}}{Causal test}    
    &  \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.5\linewidth}}{Regime 1}  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{Bitcoin $\rightarrow$ IPImicro} & 0.015     \\
                                                & (-4.71)   \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{IPImicro $\rightarrow$ Bitcoin} & 0.091**   \\
                                                & (-4.710)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{Bitcoin $\rightarrow$ IPImacro} & 0.007     \\
                                                & (-4.710)  \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{IPImacro $\rightarrow$ Bitcoin} & 0.073**   \\
                                                & (-4.710)  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize
  \note: This table presents the Transfer Entropy estimation results.  
  Standard deviation in parentheses.
  \item[***] $p < 0.01$; 
  \item[**]  $p < 0.05$; 
  \item[*]   $p < 0.10$.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!  "i would not use tabular* table environment, it not gives nice result (to my opinion)" -> what gives better results in your opinion?

Comment: @MANGo92, as  I said in mine answer ;-). and than not use `p{...}` columns,...

Comment: @MANGo92, simple tabular, consequently the table is than narrower. As is show in other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504116/134144), here is a variant that also aligns the contents of the first column with respect to the `\rightarrow`. However, I have replaced `tabular*` with `tabular` since there is a quite large amount of horizontal white space in the table. I have added some `\addlinespace` commands to provide more structure to the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Transfer Entropy Results}
  \label{tab1:entropy}
  \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{r@{}l 
                             S[input-open-uncertainty,
                               input-close-uncertainty,
                               table-space-text-post={**},
                               table-space-text-pre={(},
                               table-format=-1.3]
                             }
    \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Causal test}     &  {Regime 1}  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{Bitcoin} & \multirow{2}{*}{~\(\rightarrow\)~ IPImicro}  & 0.015     \\
                                               & & (-4.71)   \\     \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{IPImicro} & \multirow{2}{*}{~\(\rightarrow\)~ Bitcoin} & 0.091**   \\
                                               & & (-4.710)  \\     \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{Bitcoin} & \multirow{2}{*}{~\(\rightarrow\)~ IPImacro} & 0.007     \\
                                               & & (-4.710)  \\     \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{IPImacro} & \multirow{2}{*}{~\(\rightarrow\)~ Bitcoin} & 0.073**   \\
                                               & & (-4.710)  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize
  \note: This table presents the Transfer Entropy estimation results.  
  Standard deviation in parentheses.
  \item[***] $p < 0.01$; 
  \item[**]  $p < 0.05$; 
  \item[*]   $p < 0.10$.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to post the code..

Comment: @schtandard: Added. Thanks for reminding me.